# MongoDB Checkboxes, is it applicable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently working on a restaurant website, which has a CRUD system for admins to be able to create sandwiches and stuff, now I have 4 objects in the schema which are name image price and description, but I also want to add ingredients while creating, I was thinking of making checkboxes like (Tomato, Lettuce...etc), but how can I add checkboxes to the database, is there a solution or I should figure out another way to do this? 
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheeckbox is not a valid datatype in mongodb.
In order to save this information, you need to define a boolean field in your schema.

Something like this:

```
var schema = new Schema(
{
  name: String,
  Price: Number,
  Description:String,
  Ingredients:[{
    Tomato: Boolean,
    Lettuce: Boolean
 } ]
})
```

Then, this type of fields could be displayed as checkbox in the web Application.

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, that's what i needed, one more question though, can i implement this in ejs files? 
I mean like, <% if(ingredients[tomato] === true){ <h1>Tomato</h1>} ?